# replace some object properties with collection values

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

I need to iterate over an `array` with `foreach` loop

here is my `array` looks like

```
$event->menu->add( 'MEDIA' );
            $event->menu->add(
                [
                    'text'       => 'About us',
                    'icon_color' => 'green',
                    'submenu'    => [
                        [
                            'text'       => 'menu items 1',
                            'icon_color' => "lime",
                            'url'        => 'admin/link',
                        ],
                    ],
                ] );
```

now I need to replace the items in `submenu` with data coming from database

here is the loop looks like

```
$abouts = About::all();
            foreach($abouts as $about){
                [
                    'text'       => 'About us',
                    'icon_color' => "lime",
                    'url'        => 'admin/about/1/edit',
                ];
            }
```

my question is

how can I overwrite this

```
'submenu'    => [
   [
        'text'       => 'menu items 1',
        'icon_color' => "lime",
        'url'        => 'admin/link',
   ],
],
```

with my `foreach` loop

dump array looks like this

```
BuildingMenu {#256 ▼
  +menu: Builder {#246 ▼
    +menu: array:4 [▼
      0 => "MEDIA"
      1 => array:9 [▶]
      2 => "MEDIA"
      3 => array:12 [▼
        "text" => "About us"
        "icon_color" => "green"
        "submenu" => array:5 [▼
          0 => array:9 [▼
            "text" => "About us"
            "icon_color" => "lime"
            "url" => "admin/about/1/edit"
            "href" => "http://localhost:8000/admin/about/1/edit"
            "active" => true
            "classes" => array:1 [▶]
            "class" => "active"
            "top_nav_classes" => array:1 [▶]
            "top_nav_class" => "active"
          ]
        ]
        "href" => "#"
        "active" => true
        "submenu_open" => true
        "submenu_classes" => array:1 [▶]
        "submenu_class" => "treeview-menu"
        "classes" => array:2 [▶]
        "class" => "active treeview"
        "top_nav_classes" => array:2 [▶]
        "top_nav_class" => "active dropdown"
      ]
    ]
```

var-dump $about

```
Collection {#265 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => About {#266 ▼
      +translatedAttributes: array:2 [▶]
      #fillable: array:1 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      +timestamps: true
      #attributes: array:4 [▶]
      #original: array:4 [▶]
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    }
    1 => About {#267 ▶}
    2 => About {#268 ▶}
    3 => About {#269 ▶}
    4 => About {#270 ▶}
  ]
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can get `text` key from here:

```
$event->menu->menu[3]['submenu'][0]['text']
```

the same for `icon_color` and `url`

Comment: No I need to put it in array! to be clear I need to overwrite the `submenu` with the values coming from `foreach` loop

Comment: As I understand you need to do this:
`$event->menu->menu[3]['submenu'] = $abouts;`
If not, please show what is there in $abouts array:
`var_dump($abouts)`
and what do you want to do here:
`foreach($abouts as $about){
                [
                    'text'       => 'About us',
                    'icon_color' => "lime",
                    'url'        => 'admin/about/1/edit',
                ];
            }`

Comment: fine I need to add the `foreach` loop values into the `'submenu'    => []` so made the loop under the `submenu` array how to overwrite this array with the loop values, what is there in $abouts array? see my edit on the question

Comment: What methods do you have to manipulate the `Collection` object? I think there must be something like `$about->getAttributes();`
Do you use some Framework (or CMS)?